# Regular expression to match a word in js

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to match words like lay_10, lay_11, lay_20 with regex but it's not working, any help will be really appreciated.

```
var patt =new RegExp("/lay/");

if (patt.test("lay_10")){
  alert("matched");
}
```

Comment: You don't need the `/` just use `var patt =new RegExp("lay");` *or* use the literal `if (/lay/.test("lay_10"))`

Comment: yup that worked

Comment: You don't need regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite your code like the following:

```js
var patt = new RegExp("lay");

if (patt.test("lay_10")) {
  alert("matched");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const reg = /lay_([0-9]+)/g

if(reg.test(`lay_10`)) {
    console.log(`Matched`)
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

To clarify the other answers, there are two ways to define a regex in JavaScript. Either via `new RegExp("lay");` or via `/lay/`. Since you mixed the two methods, it did not work correctly.

```
var pattern1 = new RegExp("lay");
var pattern2 = new /lay/           //You can use either one.

if (pattern1.test("lay_10") && pattern2.test("lay_11")) {
  alert("matched"); // matched
}
```